# User account creation and validation (BigCommerce)

Tags: javascript, validation, account, bigcommerce

I'm having a little trouble with my account creation form.

first of all, my site is on 'BigCommerce', but they can't help me because i changed the design and they don't deal with design related issues.

The problem is like this:
If I fill every textbox with the right information and click submit, everything is just OK. I'm getting transferred to the 'Thank you' page, the new user is added and everything is just fine.

But, If I type something like a wrong E-mail address, Two not-matching passwords, leave some text box blank or something like that and click submit, the form is all blank and I have to start filling the details all over again.

second, I'm getting redirected to another page (with a new and empty form), and the error is written on the top on the form, instead of getting a pop-up message with what's wrong on the same page.

so.. this is the account creation page:
        ​

http://pastebin.com/pB5mrbtf
​

and the javascript code its redirecting to

http://pastebin.com/gLw5WCEQ

Please help

Answer (score 0):

remove the autocomplete="off" for your text removing issue and for others pls attach jsfiddle link.
Also keep your old id's and class's for validation, otherwise you need to update your js file functions also. please provide jsfiddle link